# itemHeight, height of menuItemStyleData of DropDownButton2

Tags: flutter, mobile, menuitem, dropdownbutton

```
this.height = _kMenuItemHeight,
```

https://pub.dev/packages/dropdown_button2
I'm using this package to achive the DropDownMenu under the Button. But when I'm trying to custom its itemHeight. Its seem that the height is fixed to _kMenuItemHeight instead of intrinsic height in the default DropDownButton.
Is there anyway I can achive the intrinsic height of item in the Menu?
The List itemHeight in the DropDownButton2 is still fixed instead of intrinsic.

If there can't be, is there anyway I can custom the DropDown behavior of default DropDownButton? ( Like it will drop from the bottom of the button instead of the chosen one )
Tks.

The itemHeight of DropDownButton2 will be intrinsic